# How can I check if a string is only letters in python using isalpha?

Tags: python

I am trying to check to see if a user's input only contains letters. Other forums seem like the 'isalpha' function seems to be what I'm looking for, yet when I use it in my code and run it, an error appears saying `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isalpha'`.

This is my code:

```
name='hello'
if name.isalpha():
    print("Your name is valid")
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It [definitely exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha).

Comment: How old is your version of Python?

Comment: what's the version of your python intepreter.

Comment: Works fine with me. This may seem weird but sometimes the editor I use causes such a problem, it inserts invisible chars that nevertheless make identifiers unrecognizable for the interpreter. In that case deleting it all and retyping helps, cut and paste doesn't.

Comment: Looks like the OP is using `print()` as a function, so this is probably Python 3, which should work perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the entire file you're using. Including the bit at the top, please.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Or Python 2 with `from __future__ import print_function`...

Comment: I suspect the problem is that this is not actually the code you are having a problem with ...

Comment: @twalberg, if they're able to use that import, they probably have a reasonable up-to-date version of Python 2. (Note my repeated use of "probably" :P.)

Comment: `isalpha` has been around since at least Python 2.0, released back in October 2000. I doubt this is your real code or your real error message. Check your code for typos.

Comment: Are you perhaps using an online Python editor written in Javascript? Could be a bug in that. You should report it to the website. Your code, as you have posted it, should work.

Comment: I'm learning computer science at school, in which we use Python 3.4, however I don't have Python on my laptop, so I'm using an online Python interpreter http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~kwalsh/python/.  I'm pretty sure it's the same error that comes up at school though.

Comment: @Alex: that interpreter is at best incomplete. Use a real Python interpreter instead.

Comment: @Alex Then contact your school about the error. It's from their end, not yours.

Comment: I've tried programming this code multiple times at school (my teacher won't help me as wants us to be independent and research questions ourselves) and it doesn't work, so I doubt it's a spelling error.  Is there an alternate way of checking a variable contains only letters? (One that I could understand, bearing in mind I'm a beginner)

Comment: @Alex it says right at the bottom of the page that it's an incomplete version of Python that likely has bugs in it. It's the interpreter, not you, that code should work.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that online interpreter is *very* imcomplete - `print dir("hello")` gives only `['capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'find', 'index', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rstrip', 'split', 'strip', 'upper']` - there's a *lot* missing...

Comment: But even without the interpreter, on Python at school it comes up with the same error

Comment: I just tried it  using a different interpreter (repl.it) and it worked, thanks for the help, sorry if it was a basic question

Comment: This has been implemented in skulpt since.

Answer (score 0):

As most people in the comment have mentioned that tool you have online does not work properly and you should stay away from it.

From the website you provided:

> This is a simple online Python interpreter, built using the Skulpt
>   engine (slightly modified by kwalsh).
>
> Put your Python code below (copy-and-paste or just type it in
>   directly), then click run.
>
> **Note: this isn't a complete version of Python. See below.**

If you must use an online interpreter, you might try out the engine that is provided by your school (Skulpt).

But I highly recommend you get python installed onto your laptop, you're less likely to run through any errors.

Comment: I just tried it  using a different interpreter (repl.it) and it worked, thanks for the help, sorry if it was a basic question

Comment: Just wondering, any reason why you can't/unable to install python on your laptop? It will really help especially when you progress in your class.

Comment: I'd never really thought about it to be honest, I'm not planning on doing computer science after my GCSEs, I just wanted to understand why my program didn't work which is why I asked this question.  Would it take up lots of memory on my laptop if I did install it?

Comment: All the installation files together are barely over 100MB on my machine. People run Python on [$30 computers](https://www.raspberrypi.org/). Just install it.

Comment: Absolutely, like TigerhawkT3 mentioned, it's so lightweight it won't hinder the performance of your laptop at all. You don't have to install it of course if you know for sure you're not going to use it, but it's a wonderful tool to have/play with.